# Listing files from all users' GSuite My Drive using SDK

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace

How do I as an admin list the files & their attributes from all the users GSuite My Drive using drive API regardless of file is shared or not?

Comment: Have you checked this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37602929/how-can-an-admin-access-the-google-drive-contents-of-all-the-users-in-a-particul)? It says that even as admin, you cannot access users files directly. This is achieved using [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) with [domain wide delagation authority](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#perform_g_suite_domain-wide_delegation_of_authority).

Comment: I have checked that post. However even after using service account with domain wide delegation, I was not able to get all the listing. Not sure what is missing.